# yii 1.1x: i get 404 when i try to pass a variable from view to widget

Tags: php, yii

In my yii app, i get a date string via ajax get then i try to pass it to my feature widget. The thing is that sometimes i get the date via `GET` url and sometimes i use a `default` one that i get directly in the widget (so in that case no variable needs to be passed). Here is the code:

**controller**:

```
public function actionGetDate($date) {      
    $this->render('index',array('date' =>$date));
}
```

The `$date` passes to the view without any problem.

**My view**:

```
if (isset($date))
{
    echo "$date !!!!";
    $this->widget('FullWidget',array('date2' =>$date) );
} else {
    echo "not date";
    $this->widget('FullWidget');
}
```

when `$date` is **not set**, then the code runs without any issue.

when `$date` is **set** and then it goes to this line below and it gets me 404 Error..

`$this->widget('FullWidget',array('date2' =>$date) );`

here is the error:

[image]

**FullWidget:**

```
class FullWidget extends CWidget {

    private $_userConfig;

    public function init() {

        $this->_userConfig = Yii::app()->getModule('module1234')->getDefaultConfig();     
    }

    public function run() {
    if (isset($date2))
{
    echo "yes!!!";
    //$this->render('small_Widget', array('config' => $this->_userConfig,'date' => $date2));// this line is commented and i dont run it yet. the problem is when i'm trying to pass the variable from the view to the FullWidget    
    }else{
        echo "no!!!!";
        $this->render('small_Widget', array('config' => $this->_userConfig));
    }

}
}
```

Does anybody knows whats the problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: can u show the screenshot of your 404 error?

Comment: see above. i added a picture. nothing more to it.

Comment: what is that fullwidget do? can u share its code or are u using any extension

Comment: I think its your date formatting issue, when date is set, maybe you are not sending the date with the same format that is used in ur default date.

Comment: i don't think is the date. i tried passing a random string instead of the variable. still not working. maybe it is something that i need to import? i have no idea lol

Comment: Is it rendering view ('small_Widget')  from another contoller? Is the view ('small_Widget') spelled correct?

Comment: everything is spelled alright. the flow is like this: 
url (get)-> controller -> view file -> widget - >widget view file.

right now it is stuck here: view file -> widget